# How to compile ath9k drivers from source?

Tags: drivers, compiling, kernel-modules, make, backports

I want to make some changes in `ath9k` drivers for learning purposes.
My problem is that when I try to compile the driver, the `make` command is giving many `implicit declaration` errors, `setup_timer`, `ACCESS_ONCE`, `DECLARE_EWMA` are the most frequent ones that show up in the errors.

My kernel version is `Ubuntu 4.15.0-20-generic` and I am using the driver source code from [backports-4.14-rc2-1](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.14-rc2/backports-4.14-rc2-1.tar.xz).

These are the commands I run:

```
cd backports-4.14-rc2-1
make defconfig-ath9k
make
```

I have already installed necessary header files using `build-essential`.
What should I do, so that I can compile my edited source code of drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was compiling the driver module from the torvalds linux kernel, that was the problem, now I am compiling it from the Ubuntu source code, and it is working...